# How to Traverse Dataframe particular column in the loop

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi i have the following dataframe like

```
df.show()
```

this will output like

```
+----------+--------+-------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|      date|    time|from_to|      expression_col
+----------+--------+-------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|2019-11-08|05:55:41|   MO-N|test=LN,x23=test,x5=66,lastkey1=BN zzzTemporary59 0
|2019-11-08|05:55:41|   MO-N|test=LN,x23=test,x5=66,lastkey2=BN zzzTemporary59 0
|2019-11-08|05:55:41|   MO-N|test=LN,x23=test,x5=66,lastkey3=BN zzzTemporary59 0
```

I am trying to traverse the expression_col, based on last comma seperated key before equalto sign(=) that is value are as below

```
lastkey1
lastkey2
lastkey3
```

based on this value if key is lastkey1 than then its comes under category one , lastkey2 then its comes under category 2,e.t.c
the  the final dataframe is

```
+----------+--------+-------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|      date|    time|from_to|      expression_col                                 | category
+----------+--------+-------+--------------------+-------+--------------------+
|2019-11-08|05:55:41|   MO-N|test=LN,x23=test,x5=66,lastkey1=BN zzzTemporary59 0  | category-1
|2019-11-08|05:55:41|   MO-N|test=LN,x23=test,x5=66,lastkey2=BN zzzTemporary59 0  | category-2  
|2019-11-08|05:55:41|   MO-N|test=LN,x23=test,x5=66,lastkey3=BN zzzTemporary59 0  | category-3
```

I can find the required result with the help reqular expression like

```
.*,(.*)=.*$
```

but how to can get the same thing using custom function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `expression_col` is a regular `String`:

```
scala> val df = Seq((100,"test=LN,x23=test,x5=66,lastkey1=BN zzzTemporary59"), (200,"test=LN,x23=test,x5=66,lastkey2=BN zzzTemporary59"), (300, "test=LN,x23=test,x5=66,lastkey3=BN zzzTemporary59 0")).toDF("id", "expression_col")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, expression_col: string]

scala> df.withColumn("category", concat(lit("category-"), regexp_extract(df.col("expression_col"), "lastkey(\\d+)=", 1))).show()
+---+--------------------+----------+
| id|      expression_col|  category|
+---+--------------------+----------+
|100|test=LN,x23=test,...|category-1|
|200|test=LN,x23=test,...|category-2|
|300|test=LN,x23=test,...|category-3|
+---+--------------------+----------+
```

Use a regexp that extracts at least 1 digit i.e. `\d+` from the string input, following "lastkey".

Use `concat` to add "category-" as a prefix.

Note that `df` above is a simplified version of yours.

Comment: lastkey1 was only for test purpose i need to extract the text  after last comma but before equalto sign (=)  like a string like - test=123,test4=32432,test12=test test 12 than the last comma value before the equal to sign is ----- test4

Comment: please check my comment

Comment: hm, wouldn't it be test12? In any case, you can simply change the regexp to your specification. E.g. `".*,[a-z]+(\\d+)=[^=,]+$"` would extract the digits from the last key (between comma and equals sign) starting from the end (as denoted by the dollar sign in the regexp). I.e. it would be `12` for the input in your first comment

Comment: Yes, got it i need to extract last whole text between comma and equal to sign in the regular expression (starting from end)

Comment: Hi @jacksonsmith please consider to accept the answer as correct if it is the one you were looking for